# Twig representation of array

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, twig

How can I represent array data given in the following format:

```
  array(3) { 
  [0]=> array(4) {["cohort"]=5 ["total"]=5 ["week"]=1 ["active"]=2 } 
  [1]=> array(4) {["cohort"]=5 ["total"]=5 ["week"]=2 ["active"]=1 } 
  [2]=> array(4) {["cohort"]=6 ["total"]=3 ["week"]=1 ["active"]=1 } 
  }
```

To be shown in twig like this:

```
  cohort| total| 1 (week) | 2 (week) 
  ------------------------------------
   5    |  5   | 2        | 1 
   6    |  3   | 1        | -
```

My problem, is that I don't know how to loop through the array, so that I only get row numbers equal to unique cohort number (only 5 and 6, not 5,5,6), get 'week' number as column name and 'active' value to be shown in relevant 'week' column and relevant cohort row

I tried to do this:

```
<table>
<tr><td>Cohort</td><td>Registered users</td>
    {% for week in logged_users %}
        {% if week.week_number not in weekArray %}
            <td>{{week.week_number}}</td>
            {% set weekArray = weekArray|merge([week.week_number]) %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
{% for data in logged_users %}
<tr>
    {% if data.cohort not in cohortArray %}
        <td>{{data.cohort}}</td>
        <td>{{ data.total_users }}</td>
        {% for active in logged_users %}
            <td>{{ active.active_users }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    {% set cohortArray = cohortArray|merge([data.cohort]) %}
    {% endif %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

but in the result I get this:

[image]

Comment: imo you should first transform your data so it makes more sense. Twig should not be responsible to merge the rows with the same `cohort`

Comment: @DarkBee thanks, you are right. I will change my query

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr><th>cohort</th><th>total</th><th>1 - week</th><th>2 - week</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
{% for i,a in data %}
<tr>
<td>{{ a.cohort }}</td><td>{{ a.total }}</td><td>{{ (a.week==1 ? a.active : '-') }}</td><td>{{ (a.week==2 ? a.active : '-') }</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks, but in '1 - week' 1 is value of ["week"] key, not static number